# Broadcast ARP query to all nodes?

Tags: networking, arp

I am trying to broadcast an ARP query. I want to get every node's ip and mac address updated in my system via this query. So that I can type $arp and see all the nodes on my network and their corresponding physical addresses.

I have tried `$ arping` with no avail.

```
rafael@rcepeda:/var/www/html$ arping -s 192.168.1.9 -I wlan0 192.168.1.255
ARPING 192.168.1.255 from 192.168.1.9 wlan0
^CSent 37 probes (37 broadcast(s))
Received 0 response(s)
```

#### ifconfig for my interface

`inet addr:192.168.1.9  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0`

### Regular broadcast ping

```
rafael@rcepeda:/var/www/html$ ping -b 192.168.1.255
WARNING: pinging broadcast address
PING 192.168.1.255 (192.168.1.255) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.1.255 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5040ms
```

**100% packet loss**

Is my router not letting me do this?

Comment: Are you the network admin? Let `nmap` do the work.

Comment: Sneaking ICMP ECHO broadcasts into a network was a common method of doing a denial of service attack ( [SMURF attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smurf_attack) ) so by default most routers no longer forward or respond to them. Most systems ignore them as well.

Comment: I see, it seems like this might be impossible. How is it that network discovery tools accomplish this task quickly and without permission problems?

Answer (score 2):

Most Linux distributions ignore ICMP echo broadcasts by default (kernel parameter `net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts`).

As far back as I could remember, Windows does not respond to ICMP echo broadcasts either. Maybe it could be overwritten by a registry modification but I do not know offhand.

This is discussed in the [RFC 1122 standards document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122).

I would suggest using a `bash` script like this:

```
for i in 192.168.1.{1..254} 
do
  ping -c1 $i > /dev/null || true
  arp -an $i
done
```

Comment: I ran the bash script and I get ping usage info.

Comment: Oops, just pasted my base script without modifying it for your question. Note that it'll take a while due to `ping`. You could modify timeout (`-W`, view `man ping`) accordingly.

Comment: It works, and yeah it takes a while. A network discovery tool might be better.

Comment: Depending on your use-case, I'd say something like `nmap` is infinitely better honestly.